# Chef checking log file size

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, chef-recipe, logfile

I want to create a code with chef which it test the size of log file if it exceeds `30mb` for example it will delete it in cron job.

Can you help me in it please?

this is my solution but it's not what i want:

```
execute "echo '/srv/#{app['shortname']}/current/app/log/*.log {
    rotate 1
    missingok
    copytruncate
    sharedscripts

    postrotate
            /bin/rm -rf /srv/#{app['shortname']}/current/app/log/*.log*
    endscript
}' >> /etc/logrotate.d/#{app['name']}-app-log-rotation" do
      ignore_failure true
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always create a file with the shell script to delete the file and call that file via chef cron resource

```
file '/tmp/foo.sh' do
  content "if (wc -c < /tmp/y.txt) > 3072000; then rm -f /tmp/y.txt; fi"
  mode 755
end

cron 'name_of_cron_entry' do
  minute '3'
  command 'sh -x /tmp/foo.sh  > /tmp/backup 2>&1'
end
```

This will create a cron entry for you with that script.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
file '/tmp/y.txt' do
    only_if { ::File.size('/tmp/y.txt').to_f / 1024000 > 30 }
    action :delete
end
```

Comment: But i want it to be like a cron, it mean that execute for example evry 3min